# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Multiple decimal separators in pattern

Tags: java, decimalformat

I want to format a number using a pattern in Java. I am getting error if the pattern has more than one decimal point. Here is the code :

```
    DecimalFormatSymbols symbols = new DecimalFormatSymbols();
    symbols.setDecimalSeparator(',');
    
    DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat();
    df.setDecimalFormatSymbols(symbols);
    df.applyPattern("#.###.###.###,##");
    
    String formattedValue = df.format("123456789");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was testing it and it seems like the apply pattern needs a "," as grouping separator despite the one selected with the DecimalFormatSymbols. You can customize the result setting the grouping separator in the DecimalFormatSymbols as well. This is the code I tested in a Unit Test

```
    DecimalFormatSymbols symbols = new DecimalFormatSymbols();
    symbols.setDecimalSeparator(',');
    symbols.setGroupingSeparator('.');

    DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat();
    df.setDecimalFormatSymbols(symbols);
    df.applyPattern("#,###,###,###.##");

    Assertions.assertEquals("123.456.789,25", df.format(123456789.25));
```

And use a number in the df.format argument

Comment: Thanks. It works. Is there any way I can get this result without setting decimalseparator and groupseparator explicitly? I am trying to achieve this just by using the pattern "#.###.###.###,##"

Answer (score 0):

Add the **DecimalFormatSymbols#setGroupingSeparator('.')** method to your code, for example:

```
DecimalFormatSymbols symbols = new DecimalFormatSymbols();
symbols.setDecimalSeparator(',');
symbols.setGroupingSeparator('.');  // Add This.
```

but also utilize a format that is specific to your system's current locale, for example:

```
df.applyPattern("#,###.##");
```

Notice that you really don't need to go as deep as you do with the format pattern. What is shown above will suffice. Numerical groups always contain 3 digits, you just need to specify that you want a separator character there

Also, use a number value rather than a numerical string, for example:

```
int value = 123456789; // or 123_456_789
String formattedValue = df.format(value);
```

Altogether, this should work:

```
DecimalFormatSymbols symbols = new DecimalFormatSymbols();
symbols.setDecimalSeparator(',');
symbols.setGroupingSeparator('.');     // Added this...

DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat();
df.setDecimalFormatSymbols(symbols);
df.applyPattern("#,###.##");   // Note the format pattern used.
    
int value = 123456789;**strong text**         // Use a number variable.
String formattedValue = df.format(value);
System.out.println(formattedValue);
```

**Output to console:**

```
123.456.789
```

Some countries like Italy, Spain, and Norway for example use this number format and with this in mind you could do this:

```
DecimalFormatSymbols symbols = new DecimalFormatSymbols(java.util.Locale.ITALIAN);
DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#,###.##", symbols);
int value = 123456789; // or 123_456_789
String formattedValue = df.format(value);
System.out.println(formattedValue);
```

**Output to console:**

```
123.456.789
```

Notice the **Locale** added to the **DecimalFormatSymbols** constructor (Locale.ITALIAN). Also notice the actual format. Use the format for your System's specific locale. Also notice that a **int** variable type containing a literal number is used instead of a numerical string.

Try it with a **double** type (floating point) value:

```
DecimalFormatSymbols symbols = new DecimalFormatSymbols(java.util.Locale.ITALIAN);
DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#,###.##", symbols);
double value = 1234567.89d;
String formattedValue = df.format(value);
System.out.println(formattedValue);
```

**Output to console:**

```
1.234.567,89
```